# Яндекс.Карты: как отобразить Circle поверх меток?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Метки загружаются в ObjectManager, затем ObjectManager добавляется к Map.geoObject, после этого туда же добавляются два Circle. Пытался задавать zIndex для Cirlce, для меток и для самого ObjectManager - бесполезно. Получается всё равно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать свой объект pane (dom слой на карте) указать ему zIndex (к примеру 600 что будет поверх меток) и рисовать круги в нем. Пример:

```
    var pane = new ymaps.pane.MovablePane(myMap, {
      zIndex: 600
    });
    myMap.panes.append('myAwesomePane', pane);

    var circle = new ymaps.Circle(
      [[55.751574, 37.573856], 10000], 
      {},
    {
      fillColor: 'ff000099',
      pane: 'myAwesomePane'
    })
```

Вот интерактивный пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wbn51u0a/23/